# Laravel broadcast works for one user

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast, pusher, laravel-echo

I am doing a notification tracking by following a simple example from the internet. Unfortunately, so far, I've managed to make it work for only one user. When I open two users, the message from A to B works, but from B to A does not work.
Can someone help me?

channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

bootstrap.js

```
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'some-key',
    cluster: 'mt1',
    forceTLS: true
});
```

global.js

```
    var urlChannel = 'App.User.' + $('#user_logado_id').val();
    window.Echo.private(urlChannel)
        .notification((notification) => {
            addNotificacao(notification);
        });
```

Send notification to user.

```
$user->notify(new NotificacaoPadrao($param));
```

I would like notifications to be sent to all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass both sender and receiver `user_id`. So in your `channels.php`:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{from_user_id}.{to_user_id}', function ($user, $from_user_id, $to_user_id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $from_user_id || (int) $user->id === (int) $to_user_id;
});
```

When doing this, you should remember that both user must call the same channel name. E.g. If you have user `1` and `2` sending messages to each other the URL channel of both should be 'App.User.1.2' and NOT 'App.User.2.1'.

Actually there are many ways to do this, one solution is what I mentioned above, but this only works on 1-1 messaging, NOT group message. When you want to send a group message you should create 2 tables: `channels` (id, name) and `channel_users` (id, channel_id, user_id). And your broadcasts channel route will be like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{channel_id}', function ($user, $channel_id) {
    return ChannelUser::where('channel_id', $channel_id)->where('user_id', $user->id)->exists();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but as far as you understand, the notification source is not on the client but on the server. The server sends to a specific user or several. I am wrong?
I see no point in creating a channel between two users in my case.

Comment: As I understand it, your solution would be more elegant, but what do you mean, is that to send notifications users have to be on the same channel? A simpler way would be to use a unique channel name for this?

Comment: Yes, users have to be in the same channel, to send and receive notifications. You have to insert a channel first. Obviously, users not in the channel will not be able to receive notifications.

Comment: According to this logic, should this not work?  Broadcast::channel('notification', function ($user) {
    return true;
}); Just for tests....

Comment: Well, it would work, but it will send notifications to ALL users.

Comment: Here's the explanation for that. The route broadcast should return a boolean `true` or `false`. The user will receive a notification if the return value is `true`. If the return value is false the user will not receive a notification.

Comment: Now I understand the concept well, but I'm testing with two logged in users, but only one gets the notification via websocket, something I'm missing?

Comment: @WilsonRibeiro, as what i've explained above, in order for others to receive notifications, both should listen to the same url channel. Base on your code in the question both user is receiving different url channel. E.g. If user 1 and 2 is chatting, user 1 is using the channel `App.User.1` and user 2 is using the channel `App.User.2`. Hence only 1 is receiving the message. The users must use the SAME channel in order to receive the message.

Answer (score 0):

That's because first user's channel is App.User.1, and second one is App.User.2. You should create a channel that's shared for both of them. For example: App.Channel.1-2.

Comment: But doesn't it send notification to each user's private channel? or do i have to use only one channel for all users?

Comment: Do you want to send notification to all users, or a private 1-1 channel?

Comment: I have an invitation system, when user A invites B, the global.js code is fired, but when B invites A, the notification is sent, but does not fire the global.js code

Comment: It should be working. If `$('#user_loagdo_id')` has value of currently logged-in user, then you are listening to events correctly. Then you must have an error in your backend.